# How to use the sails framework websocket proxy server

Tags: node.js, sails.js, http-proxy

I have a node server, which uses the sails framework.

Now, I have a websocket connection, through which to forward to another server.

I know how to use node solution。However, I am helpless to sails.

Please help me, grateful!